# Free Sonar instanse for open-sourced projects

Tags: java, open-source, instance, sonarqube

I know that for Apache foundation projects there is https://analysis.apache.org/

Is there free Sonar instance for open-sourced projects?

UPDATE: ASF Sonar Instance is [deprecated and removed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/INFRA/SonarQube+Analysis) as of 29th November 2019.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a public free instance of Sonar at https://sonarcloud.io
which is free for open source projects